# Can we capture phase in IBM Quantum Experience?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

[image]

I have a sample IBM experience circuit which generates $$\frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle - |01\rangle - |10\rangle + |11\rangle)$$ 
When we measure the state will be either $|00\rangle$/$|01\rangle$/$|10\rangle$/$|11\rangle$.

I know that state phase disappears after measurement. I am testing a complex circuit which involves phase angles and I want to ask my questionusing a simple state as mentioned above.

Is there anyway to know if the circuit has produced my desired state. I want to view the full state.

Comment: Click on the icon with graph on left hand-side from window with qasm code. You will see theoretical output od the circuit.

Answer (score 3):

[image]Click on the icon with graph on left hand-side from window with qasm code. You will see theoretical output of the circuit.

+1 for Martin Vesely's comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the QASM of your circuit, you can load this into Qiskit and run the circuit on the state vector simulator. This will show you what the final state vector of your circuit is.

You can load the circuit by using `QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str('your QASM')` and you can then get the simulator using `Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')`.